# SQL Server 2014 filter by length and value

Tags: sql-server, filtering

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I need a way to filter out values in my table column of any length, for example I want to filter out all the zeros of any length.

A select statement that can return '0' or '00' or '000' and so on.

```
SELECT * 
FROM <my_table>
WHERE <my_column> LIKE <condition>
```

Returns

```
0
00
000
etc
```

Comment: What about columns that include non-zero characters> What about `a00` or `00a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of filtering by one repeated character:

```
WHERE <my_column> LIKE '%0%' AND <my_column> NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
```

That is, the column must contain at least one zero and must not contain non-zeroes anywhere.

For more complicated patterns, `LIKE` tends to break down quickly.

Comment: In that case the first character would be a `0` too. You could change the first condition to `LIKE '0%'` and convert the table scan to an index seek.